# Java JOptionePane.showInputDialog change characters to * for password input

Tags: java, input, joptionpane

I want the user to put his password into a Inputdialog. But I want that the text in the textfield are e.g. stars (***), so no one can read which password is written.

I use this Code for the Inputdialog (the password will be saved in the pw variable):

```
String pw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password:");
```

Comment: Don't do the `new String(pass.getPassword())` in the accepted answer though, that will put your entered password into memory without encrypting, and with no control of when and if it will ever be removed (ie gc).

Answer (score -1):

Use JPasswordField instead

There's a tutorial here
http://www.zentut.com/java-swing/creating-password-field-by-using-jpasswordfield-class/

Comment: An answer containing only a link is not a good answer.  An answer needs to have enough information to be useful on its own, since other sites’ URLs change or disappear over time.